# fetching paginated data from related entities using Spring Data R2dbc

Tags: java, spring-data, r2dbc

How to implement the following in a r2dbc .

I have an entity CatalogItem which internally references CatalogType and CatalogBrand. Since reactive doesn't have support for JPA, one of the choice is Spring data r2dbc. I want to fetch a paged List of CatalogItems along with CatalogTypeName & CatalogBrandName but in a non blocking way.

One idea was to fetch the 3 tables data separately, iterating over them and populating the CatalogBrandName & CatalogTypeName. But i don't know how to do this in a non blocking manner using reactor.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: did you try to use 'join' operator ? of multiple reactive queries into a single response